# How to use ng-disabled to prevent user from resubmitting form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to prevent user from resubmitting the login form with the code below

```
<button class="submit" ng-disabled="form_login.$submitted" type="submit"></button>
```

But this will disable the submit button as long as the button is clicked, even when user submit invalid data. What is the right way to stop submit button only after valid information submitted?

Comment: did you try with 'form_login.$invalid'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`ng-required`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input) attribute(`directive`) which will check the `dirty` state of the element.

Try this:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.8"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <form action="#" method="post" name="myForm">
    Name::
    <input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-required='true'>
    <input type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

[Live example](http://plnkr.co/edit/OTJWUPoJo0tv4t4kYOS7?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Though your question is not clear, But you can try this ,

Here is HTML :

```
<form action="#" method="post">
  Name::<input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-keyup="dirty()">
  Address::<input type="text" ng-model="address" ng-keyup="dirty()">
  <input type="submit" ng-disabled="error" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

and here is JS :

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope){

     $scope.error = true;  //Disables button initially

     $scope.dirty = function(){
         if($scope.name!='' && $scope.address!='')//Check conditions here
          {
            $scope.error = false;  //Enables the button
          } 
     }
});
```